# conda activates environment in Anaconda promt but python imports modules from Anaconda base

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, environment

I'm new to python, Anaconda and shell scripting. I want to run some python scripts from Anaconda promt or any other shell, like this:

> main.py --epoch 25 --learning_rate .0001

I'm working on Window10 with Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7

I'm using Anaconda promt because I need to activate a special Python environment.
"activate myEnv" is working and "conda list" gives back all packages installed there.
But I get lots of ModuleNotFoundErrors when the script starts. But the packeges are installed in that environment and when I run the script in Visual Studio Code, its fine. I added some of the missing modules in the base-environment and the errors dissapeared, so I guess, python is running from there.
The expected behaviour for me would be, activating an environment in Anaconda promt and running the script from there, executes in that environment.

But perhaps it's a path issue? Or I have a general missunderstanding of this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projekte\KI\Python\Creative-Adversarial-Networks GPU Test\main.py", line 131, in <module>
    from model import DCGAN
  File "D:\Projekte\KI\Python\Creative-Adversarial-Networks GPU Test\model.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

"tensorflow" is just a sample, he could not find "numpy" and many others modules as well.

```
sys.path
[
'D:\\Projekte\\KI\\Python\\Creative-Adversarial-Networks GPU Test', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\o8\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'
]
```

conda info -a

```
(tf-gpu1.9) PS C:\Users\o8> conda info

     active environment : tf-gpu1.9
    active env location : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\o8\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\o8\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
       base environment : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\o8\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\o8\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\o8\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\o8\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

(tf-gpu1.9) PS C:\Users\o8> conda info -a

     active environment : tf-gpu1.9
    active env location : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\o8\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\o8\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
       base environment : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\o8\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\o8\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\o8\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\o8\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3
env_tensorflow           C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\env_tensorflow
python2.7                C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\python2.7
tensorflow1              C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1
tensorflow1x             C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1x
tf-gpu                   C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu
tf-gpu1.9             *  C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9

sys.version: 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [...
sys.prefix: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3
sys.executable: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\python.exe
conda location: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-debug: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-debug.exe
conda-develop: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-render: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-render.exe
conda-server: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-skeleton: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
conda-verify: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-verify.exe
user site dirs: C:\Users\o8\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35
                C:\Users\o8\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37
                C:\Users\o8\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: tf-gpu1.9
CONDA_EXE: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9
CONDA_PREFIX_1: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1x
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (tf-gpu1.9)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_ROOT: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 2
CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2
HOMEPATH: \Users\o8
NVTOOLSEXT_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
PATH: C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Library\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Scripts;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\bin;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.5.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\o8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\o8\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\o8\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\bin;.
PSMODULEPATH: C:\Users\o8\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

Path, again for better reading:

```
PATH: 
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Library\usr\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Library\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\Scripts;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu1.9\bin;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\condabin;
C:Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin;
C:Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\libnvvp;
C:Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;
C:Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:Windows\system32;
C:Windows;
C:Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
C:Windows\System32\OpenSSH;
C:Program Files\nodejs;
C:Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;
C:Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.5.0;
C:Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;
C:Users\o8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:Users\o8\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
C:Users\o8\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:Users\o8\Anaconda3\Library\bin;.
PSMODULEPATH: 
C:Users\o8\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
```

Comment: Your expected behaviour is correct. I'm relatively convinced that you're not correctly installing libraries into the actual environment that you're activating, but we can't see that workflow

Comment: I install libraries with an activated environment from conda promt using "conda install" or "pip install". Running scripts from Visual Code everything workes like expected. Can there anywhere be a path variable that confuses python or the shell to use the base env?

Comment: I added the output sys.path and of "Conda info -a"

Comment: Have you made any modifications to PATH yourself (i.e. added anaconda folders yourself)?

Comment: I tried a lot after much googling, perhaps I changed something I can't remember...perhaps it's a problem with PYTHONPATH, PATH or other environment variables?

Comment: @maxoak, Is your problem resolved now? If so, please specify your solution here so that community can benefit from it. Thanks!